# Trying to create a basic google Map with a button that can find my current location

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to create a basic webpage using the googlemaps geolocation.  I have the map embedded easily enough, but cannot get the "Find Me Button" to work.  What have I done wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#" id="get_location">Find Me</a>
<div id="map">
    <iframe id="google_map" width="425" height ="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth = "0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk?output=embed"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    var c =function (pos) {
        var lat = pos.coords.latitude,
                long = pos.coords.longitude,
            coords = lat + ', ' + long;

        document.getElementById('google_map').setAttribute('src',     'https://maps.google.co.uk/?q=' + coords + '&z=60&output=embed');

    document.getElementById('get_location').onclick = function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(c);
        return false; 
    }

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

The Find Me button does not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing brace for the c() function.

```
var c = function(pos) {
    var lat = pos.coords.latitude,
      long = pos.coords.longitude,
      coords = lat + ', ' + long;

    document.getElementById('google_map').setAttribute('src', 'https://maps.google.co.uk/?q=' + coords + '&z=60&output=embed');
} // <-- HERE

document.getElementById('get_location').onclick = function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(c);
  return false;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xot1fhsd/